# Extending a commutative diagram of exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a ring and $L_1,L_2,M_2,M_2,N_1,N_2$ $R$-modules. Say you have the following diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> L_1 @>{f_1}>> M_1 @>{g_1}>> N_1 @> >> 0\\
@. @V{\alpha}VV @V{\beta}VV @V{\gamma}VV\\
0 @>{}>> L_2 @>{f_2}>> M_2 @>{g_2}>> N_2 @> >> 0
\end{CD}

which is commutative, with exact lines.

**Problem:** Show that there are a $R$-module $M$ and $R$-module morphisms $\beta_1: M_1 \to M$ and $\beta_2: M \to M_2$ such that $\beta_2 \circ \beta_1 = \beta$ and

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> L_1 @>{f_1}>> M_1 @>{g_1}>> N_1 @> >> 0\\
@. @V{\alpha}VV @V{\beta_1}VV @V{1}VV\\
0 @>{}>> L_2 @>{f}>> M @>{g}>> N_1 @> >> 0 \\
@. @V{1}VV @V{\beta_2}VV @V{\gamma}VV\\
0 @>{}>> L_2 @>{f_2}>> M_2 @>{g_2}>> N_2 @> >> 0
\end{CD}

is a commutative diagram with exact lines.

**Attempt:** Given the scenario, the natural path I see is to choose $M = M_1 \oplus M_2$, $f(x) := (0, f_2(x))$ and $g(x,y) := g_1(x)$, which in turn does not work - some squares don't commute, and the middle line is not exact. This left me in a stump, as I can't define any other $f,g$ that do the job.

So, either my choice of $M$ was poorly made, or I am missing something. Can anyone lend me a hand?

Comment: I believe that the middle right module should be $N_1$ and not $N_2$. Try with $M=M_2\times_{N_2} N_1=\{(m,n)\in M_2\times N_1~|~ g_2(m)=\gamma(n)\}$.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a solution, following @Roland's suggestion (see comments), which I now post here to close the question.

Define $M = \{(m,n) \in M_2 \times N_1 : g_2(m) = \gamma(n)\}$. In this case, given
\begin{align}
f: L_2 & \to M  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  & g:M &\to N_1 \\
\ell & \mapsto (f_2(\ell),0) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  & (m,n) &\mapsto n
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\beta_1f: M_1 & \to M  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  & \beta_2:M &\to M_2 \\
m & \mapsto (\beta(m), g_1(m)) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  & (m,n) &\mapsto n
\end{align}
one has the following.

1. The sequence
   $$\begin{CD}
   0 @>{}>> L_2 @>{f}>> M @>{g}>> N_1 @> >> 0
   \end{CD}$$
   is exact. It is clear that $f$ is injective, $g$ is surjective and $g \circ f = 0$. Thus, it only remains to show that $\operatorname{Ker}g \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}f$. If $(m,n) \in \operatorname{Ker}g$, then $0 = g(m,n) = n \implies 0 = \gamma(n) = g_2(n) \implies n \in \operatorname{Im}f_2$, thus $(m,n) = (f_2(n_0),0)$, for some $n_0 \in L_2$.
2. The square
   $$\begin{CD}
   L_1 @>{f_1}>> M_1 \\
   @V{\alpha}VV @V{\beta_1}VV \\
   L_2 @>{f}>> M
   \end{CD}$$
   is commutative, as $\beta_1 \circ f_1(\ell) = \beta_1(f_1(\ell)) = (\beta(f_1(\ell))), g_1(f_1(\ell)) = (f_2(\alpha(\ell), 0) = f_2 \circ \alpha(\ell), \ \forall \ell \in L_2$.
3. The square
   $$\begin{CD}
   M_1 @>{g_1}>> N_1 \\
   @V{\beta_1}VV @V{1}VV \\
   M @>{g}>> N_1
   \end{CD}$$
   is commutative, as $g\circ \beta_1(m) = g(\beta(m), g_1(m)) = g_1(m),\ \forall m\in L_2$.
4. The square
   $$\begin{CD}
   L_2 @>{f}>> M \\
   @V{1}VV @V{\beta_2}VV \\
   L_2 @>{f_2}>> M_2
   \end{CD}$$
   is commutative, as $\beta_2 \circ f(\ell) = \beta_2(f_2(\ell), 0) = f_2(\ell), \ \forall \ell \in L_2$.
5. The square
   $$\begin{CD}
   M @>{g}>> N_1 \\
   @V{\beta_2}VV @V{\gamma}VV \\
   M_2 @>{g_2}>> N_2
   \end{CD}$$
   is commutative, as $g_2 \circ \beta_2(m,n) = g_2(m) = \gamma(n) = \gamma \circ g(m,n), \ \forall (m,n) \in M$.

The result follows.

Comment: Yes, there are some typos but that's it. (+1). Two comments about the problem : 1) another possible choice is $M=M_1\coprod_{L_1} L_2= M_1\oplus L_2/\{(f_1(l),-\alpha(l)) ; l\in L_1\}$. 2) A morphism of short exact sequence which induces an isomorphism at the level of the kernels (resp. cokernel) mean that the right (resp. left) commutative square is cartesian (resp. cocartesian). This is why $M$ I suggested you to look at this module.